# php redirect to current or same page

Tags: php

I am trying to create a login/register in native php,
by using 
`$goto = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

`<a href=login.php?goto=$goto>Login</a>`

It works on the login page, but not in the register.php
how to pass the
`$goto = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` from login to register.php an vice-versa

Thank you for the responses friends, I want to user this code in register.php
I wish to pass this `$goto = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to any page I want
I want to pass the `$goto = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` from login.php to register.php

Please refer this working link 
http://dailywages.esy.es/
Please go through the pages

Comment: This question is very unclear.  Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Store it in a session variable, then access the variable when needed.

Comment: If you don't want sessions you can put it into a hidden input ` <input type="hidden" name="goto_url" value="<?php echo $goto; ?>" /> ` and collect it as ` $_POST['goto_url'];`  if your form is submitted by the POST method - which it should be for things relating to logins for better security.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the php tags  - and you need to learn what urlencode does from the PHP docs

```
<a href="login.php?goto=<?php echo urlencode($goto);?>">Login</a>
```

or maybe you want them to go to the preivous page?

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>">Go back</a>
```

or after successful login

```
<?php header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); exit; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

```
<a href="login.php?goto=<?= urlencode( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ?>">Login</a>
```

or

```
echo '<a href="login.php?goto='.urlencode($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'">Login</a>';
```

Now when you go to login.php, the variable goto is set to the current page.

Another solution, not as good, is to send the user back to the refering page, if login was successful::

```
// index.php
if ( $login == true )
    header( 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
```